# Edit Rows with a dropdownlist PHP

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I want to edit a specific row (of course the one you choosed), like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpvxJ.png)

And this works fine for the most of the rows, but i have a problem with the ones which are submitted with a dropdownlist. When i'm going to edit, i want that i can update that row with another dropdownlist and that the value of the Row is first choosed, so that you can clearly see which value was in there (and maybe you dont't want to change the Value from the dropdownlist, but you have to change it aswell, because the value which was in the row is not selected:
For the better understanding:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAU9y.png)

Lets say in the "lieferant" field was Microsoft. Now i want to change the row "name", but because the dropdownlist here is showing me the first value of the dropdownlist, i have to change it everytime again to microsoft.

This is my dropdownlist (in submitting file and update file):

```
    <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="formGroupExampleInput2">Lieferant</label>
                            
                                                    <?php

$sql5= "SELECT lieferantID, lieferantname FROM lieferant";
$result5 = $connection ->query($sql5);

if ($result5->num_rows > 0) {

    echo"<select name='lieferantID'>";
    while ($row2 = $result5 ->fetch_assoc()){
    echo"<option value='" . $row2['lieferantID']. "'>" . $row2['lieferantname'] . "</option>";


    }
    echo"</select>";

}

?>
</div>
```

Here is the update query:

```
$update=mysqli_query($connection,"UPDATE kunde_projekt SET kundenname_projekt='$kundenname_projekt', standort='$standort', info_uebergabe='$info_uebergabe', kstnr='$kstnr', InvestPSPID='$investpspid' WHERE kundeprojekt_id='$kundeprojekt_id'");
```

And here the button where the "kstnr" and "kostenstelle" are submitted to the update file:

```
<td> <button class="btn-primary btn"> <a href="updateliste.php? kstnr=<?php print $row['kstnr']; ?>&kostenstelle=<?php print $row['kostenstelle']; ?>" class="text-white"> Update </a> </button> </td>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You might need "ajax" for subsequent "rows", so that its not all pre-rendered in the html/dom.

Answer (score 0):

You need a "selected" tag in the dropdown list.

see:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp

You need to get the existing value from your row, and then check inside your loop: does the current item match the one im adding to the list right now? If yes add "Selected" to the code.

eg:

```
echo"<option value='" . $row2['lieferantID']. "'>" . $row2['lieferantname'] . "</option>";
```

becomes (assuming your existing row data is in $myDetails):

```
if($row2['lieferantID'] == $myDetails['liferant']) 
{
    $selected = "Selected" ;
} else {
    $selected = "";
}
echo"<option value='" . $row2['lieferantID'] . "' '. $selected.' >" . $row2['lieferantname'] . "</option>";
```

The if statement can be shortened with ternary operators if you like too.